# Quickly switching ISP accounts on a router

Tags: router

I have a `D-Link DSL-2750U` Router.
 I have two different ISP account.

I have tried setting up multiple ISP profiles on my router , but is seems like the VPI/VCI combination needs to be unique. In my Case both my ISP use the same.

Is there a script/app/method I could use to quickly switch my ISP profiles on my router?

Going in and manually editing it is such an arduous process. (I'm lazy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some research and the easiest way I found was to make a script using [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) 
My source was the following [forum post](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/543533-D-Link-DSL-2750U-Multiple-ADSL-accounts-on-one-router).

I made 2 scripts and compiled them. Now I just run the correct .exe on my desktop and it does all the clicking for me.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/NdHy0KtA) is a link to the script I made.

Comment: thanks for script.but it stop working on login popup of DLINK DSL-2640U. any idea?